# SSH key authentication login issue with PAM

Tags: ssh, centos7, pam

After setting up key authentication for SSH i'm having the following error :

```
ssh remoteHost
System is going down.

Connection to remoteHostAddress closed by remote host. 
Connection to remoteHostAddress closed.
```

The ssh -vvv result:

```
ssh -vvv prod08
OpenSSH_7.2p2, LibreSSL 2.4.1
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/adriendauchez/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/adriendauchez/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for prod08
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "prod08.finansemble.fr" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to prod08.finansemble.fr [92.243.15.18] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/adriendauchez/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/adriendauchez/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to prod08.finansemble.fr:22 as 'finman'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/adriendauchez/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /Users/adriendauchez/.ssh/known_hosts:12
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from prod08.finansemble.fr
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:kaUPG6K75V3HEen+o60LKipDVhVJatP/a1WAcoQK5Lc
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/adriendauchez/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /Users/adriendauchez/.ssh/known_hosts:12
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from prod08.finansemble.fr
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/adriendauchez/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /Users/adriendauchez/.ssh/known_hosts:13
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 92.243.15.18
debug1: Host 'prod08.finansemble.fr' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/adriendauchez/.ssh/known_hosts:12
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: key: /Users/adriendauchez/.ssh/id_rsa (0x7f8370700350), explicit, agent
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/adriendauchez/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp SHA256:ok0cG8G7pYSJlGM9L6pMsAJk6vmdLKYhX/pwkNps7zU
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:ok0cG8G7pYSJlGM9L6pMsAJk6vmdLKYhX/pwkNps7zU
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 53
debug3: input_userauth_banner
System is going down.

debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to prod08.finansemble.fr ([92.243.15.18]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug3: send packet: type 1
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t3 r-1 i0/0 o0/0 fd 6/7 cc -1)

Connection to prod08.finansemble.fr closed by remote host.
Connection to prod08.finansemble.fr closed.
Transferred: sent 2580, received 2704 bytes, in 0.0 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 10113368.5, received 10599437.4
debug1: Exit status -1
```

The var log secure error is :

```
 fatal: Access denied for user finman by PAM account configuration [preauth]
```

So i tried different workarounds to connect and setting `UsePAM` to `no` allowed me to be able to connect via ssh to the server.

pam.d/sshd :

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth       required pam_sepermit.so
auth       substack     password-auth
auth       include      postlogin
# Used with polkit to reauthorize users in remote sessions
-auth      optional     pam_reauthorize.so prepare
account    required     pam_nologin.so
account    include      password-auth
password   include      password-auth
# pam_selinux.so close should be the first session rule
session    required     pam_selinux.so close
session    required     pam_loginuid.so
# pam_selinux.so open should only be followed by sessions to be executed in the user context
session    required     pam_selinux.so open env_params
session    required     pam_namespace.so
session    optional     pam_keyinit.so force revoke
session    include      password-auth
session    include      postlogin
# Used with polkit to reauthorize users in remote sessions
-session   optional     pam_reauthorize.so prepare
```

After searching and trying differents solutions i haven't found a way to keep PAM enabled and connect to the server.

More info: connecting from a mac to a remote CentOS 7

The question is, does anyone know why PAM would block the ssh connection via pubkey ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your logs indicate that you authenticated just fine, but that you received the message `System is going down` and were disconnected.

Look for a file `/etc/nologin` and remove it.

This file is created when the system is shutting down or restarting, and its presence indicates that users should not be allowed to log in, because the *system is going down*.

This file *should* be removed upon restart, but if that didn't happen, then the system could be up and running normally but still not allow anyone to log in.

Comment: Specifically, the message and failure comes from a PAM module, [`pam_nologin.so`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_nologin) that checks for the existence of the `/etc/nologin` (or other) file and fails non-root logins while it is present.

Comment: Unfortunately i don't have a nologin file in /etc. 
Moreover i i found out that after disabling PAM on sshd_config i am able to connect via shh using password even though i specified PasswordAuthentication no